# Foreach doesn't return all values in array

Tags: php, codeigniter

Struggling to understand why the foreach loop in the function doesn't print out all of the values in the includes array. Any help is much appreciated.

Array $this->includes:

```
Array (
    [0] => http://localhost/assets/css/style.css
    [1] => http://localhost/assets/css/internal.css
    [2] => http://localhost/assets/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css
    [3] => http://localhost/assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js
)
```

Function:

```
public function print_includes()
{
    print_r($this->includes);
  // Initialize a string that will hold all includes
  $final_includes = '';
  foreach ($this->includes as $include)
  {
    // Check if it's a JS or a CSS file
    if (preg_match('/js$/', $include))
    {
      // It's a JS file
      $final_includes .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $include . '"></script>';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/css$/', $include))
    {
      // It's a CSS file
      $final_includes .= '<link href="' . $include . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
    }
    return $final_includes;
  }
}
```

What's printed with $this->layouts->print_includes():

```
<link href="http://localhost/assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>
```

Comment: What is getting returned?

And just to confirm, you are using echo to display the results correct?

Comment: Have you checked that there's no spaces at the end of those urls that could be throwing off the regexes?

Comment: @tehlulz yes, it looks like the answer is the return was inside the inner loop and it shouldn't have been.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your return statement is inside the foreach loop, so it only ever concatenates the first link element and then returns the string as the result of the function. Try moving it outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks -- that one is embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Place you return out of foreach loop

```
foreach ($this->includes as $include)
  {
    // Check if it's a JS or a CSS file
    if (preg_match('/js$/', $include))
    {
      // It's a JS file
      $final_includes .= '';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/css$/', $include))
    {
      // It's a CSS file
      $final_includes .= '';
    }
  }
return $final_includes;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using the return inside the foreach which cause it to stop after first loop

```
public function print_includes()
{
    print_r($this->includes);
  // Initialize a string that will hold all includes
  $final_includes = '';
  foreach ($this->includes as $include)
  {
    // Check if it's a JS or a CSS file
    if (preg_match('/js$/', $include))
    {
      // It's a JS file
      $final_includes .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $include . '"></script>';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/css$/', $include))
    {
      // It's a CSS file
      $final_includes .= '<link href="' . $include . '" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';
    }
   }
    return $final_includes;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `foreach` loop is incorrect

```
foreach($this->includes as $inc) {

    return $final_includes; # should not be here.
}
```